# WordPress broken pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Pagination on my custom post page was working fine but after adding few posts it got broken - the older post link is not working any more.

Please suggest how can I fix it? I have tried disabling plugins, changing permalinks and almost anything i could find easy on the WordPress Codex.

Here's my query with pagination:

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'press' , 'posts_per_page' => 50 , 'paged' => $paged);
query_posts( $args );
/*Setting up our custom query (In here we are setting it to show 12 posts per page and eliminate all sticky posts) */
//query_posts ( $args );//query_posts($query_string . '&caller_get_posts=6&posts_per_page=12');
?>
<ul class="griditemleft clear">
    <?php if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('category-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                <h2 class="press-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>

<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve, but I think you want to look closely at http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Custom_Queries_using_Offset_and_Pagination

Specifying hard-coded offsets in queries can and will break pagination since offset is used by WordPress internally to calculate and handle pagination.

To get around this limitation, you will need to write some additional code to manually handle pagination; you need to detect whether a loop has additional pages and then dynamically calculate the appropriate offset for the current page.

The code for controlling custom pagination will all occur within your functions.php file and not within the template page.php You can set an initial offset, as well as redefine the number of posts per page. There are specific samples displayed on the codex link above.

You will be adding the action before the query is run, via

```
   add_action('pre_get_posts', 'myprefix_query_offset', 1 );
```

and you will have to account for the customization via

```
   add_filter('found_posts', 'myprefix_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );
```